# writeBuffer of ExcelJS doesn't return Buffer type

Tags: node.js, buffer, arraybuffer, exceljs

I'm using [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) with Typescript in my project. But `writeBuffer()` function returns `ExcelJS.Buffer` instead of `Buffer` type. And since `ExcelJS.Buffer` inherits from `ArrayBuffer`, converting `ArrayBuffer` to `Buffer` will break excel file. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance!

```js
declare interface Buffer extends ArrayBuffer { }
```

```js
let resultExcel: Buffer; // buffer
const tmpResultExcel: ExcelJS.Buffer = await tmpWorkBook.xlsx.writeBuffer(); // arraybuffer
resultExcel = Buffer.from(tmpResultExcel); // doesn't work well
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the problem with `tmpWorkBook.xlsx.writeBuffer();` comes from a wrong returned type definition, in my point of view.

if you try `Buffer.isBuffer(tmpResultExcel)`, you see that `tmpResultExcel` is an actual JavaScript Buffer.

You can solve the type issue with

```
const tmpResultExcel: any = await tmpWorkBook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
```

and you can use tmpResultExcel as a buffer in your code.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this one too and this is 2022 with exceljs' latest version (4.3.0 at time of writing).

As @Frédéric Lang stated it is indeed a typing problem. Moreover even though inspecting the provided types did not lead to a clear solution, as the `workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()` function's signature tells us it returns a plain `Buffer`.

Instead of converting the dodgy `exceljs.Buffer` instance to `any`, you may just want to "cast" it to a proper `Buffer` after an `await`.

```
private async writeXlsxBuffer(data: BillingSummaryFileLine[]): Promise<Buffer> {
        const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
        await workbook.xlsx.readFile("my_model.xlsx");
        ...
        return await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer() as Buffer;
    }
```

You will have to make sure this is actually a `Buffer` though, as using the `as` keyword Typescript will assume you know what you are doing casting one object to another type.